# How to start observable in the pipe in RxJS 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have this RxJS code in my Angular project:

```js
settingsService.getSetting('setting-name').pipe(
  map((setting: SettingInterface) => {
    // ...

    return setting;
  }),
  tap((setting: SettingInterface) => this.settingService.save(setting)),
  map((setting: SettingInterface) => {
    // ...
  })
);
```

In this code the `this.settingService.save(setting)` is an `Observable` too, and it isn't subscribed.

How can I start this observable in the pipe, wait for it and continue?

Important:

- the `save()` observable must start after prevoius `map()` operator
- the result of the `save()` observable is irrelevant in the pipe and I want to drop it
- the `save()` observable must start before next `map()` operator

Is there any RxJS operator to do this?

Comment: Use `concatMap` like this `concatMap((setting: SettingInterface) => this.settingService.save(setting))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an observable that depends on another observable, you could use one of the RxJS's higher order mapping operator like `switchMap`, `concatMap`, `flatMap` or `exhaustMap`. Each has their own purpose. [Here's](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) a good rundown. Essentially, upon subscription they convert one observable to another and return the modified observable.

I'll use [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to illustrate.

```js
settingsService.getSetting('setting-name').pipe(
  map((setting: SettingInterface) => {
    // ...

    return setting;
  }),
  switchMap((setting: SettingInterface) => 
    this.settingService.save(setting).pipe(map(_ => setting))
  ),
  map((setting: SettingInterface) => {
    // ...
  })
);
```

You'll notice I've piped in another `map` to the inner obesrvable: `.pipe(map(saved => setting))`. Without this the following outer `map` would receive the output from `this.settingService.save(setting)` instead of the `setting` variable that you require.